# Error in using dashing on raspbian

Tags: ruby, linux, raspberry-pi

I've trying to implement dashing on a raspberry(1) witj raspbian (jessie lite).
Once i've installed raspbian, i've done the following things with success :

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install bundler
sudo apt-get install rubygems
sudo gem install dashing

sudo dashing new dashboard_project

I get the following error :

/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- json (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/dashing-1.3.7/lib/dashing/downloader.rb:3
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/dashing-1.3.7/bin/dashing:7
        from /usr/local/bin/dashing:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/dashing:23

Do you have any idea  of what should i do ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Post 'gem list json' to see whether json module is installed. If not, then try installing it with 'gem install json'.

Comment: it only gives me

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

so i tried to installed it but it gives me : 
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        json requires Ruby version ~> 2.0.
 and when i do ruby -v i get > 2 version
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13) [arm-linux-gnueabihf]

Comment: From the path you provided in your answer, it seems that your default ruby is 1.8. Check what version exactly are you running. Maybe something like `gem -v` might help to see what is being run as gem.

Comment: indeed i got the version 1.8.24. How do i update it ?

Comment: i get  ruby >2, but json still not installing, saying, i need ruby version>2

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo gem install json
Fetching: json-2.0.2.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        json requires Ruby version ~> 2.0.
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13) [arm-linux-gnueabihf]
pi@raspberrypi:~ $

Comment: Aren't you running some older version of gem?